# Durandal SPA. Browsers do not show scrollbars

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, durandal

My durandal spas do not show the vertical scrollbar when content is longer than the page height. I can´t figure the reason for this strange behaviour. Why is that? How can I set durandal to show scrollbar automatically?

Thank you.

Comment: I do not believe this is a problem with Durandal, but with your CSS. However, it is impossible to say without more detail.

Comment: Agreed; sounds more like you've got overflow set to "hidden" somewhere in your CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Check firebug for any js error , some times if u have js error browser scroll bar gets hidden..